# How to make an Existing Android app in Google play store to paid app

Tags: android, google-play

Already I am having a free Android app in Google play store. Now as per our requirement I want to change it to paid app. But somewhere I found that a free app cannot be changed to paid app whereas a paid app can be changed to free app. Then presently how can I achieve that???

Comment: You are right. You cannot undo you choice of pricing of the app. You could take down the app and re-upload it as a paid one (if it is not againts googles policy).

Comment: Thats rule of google you cannot make your free app to paid app

Comment: I agree with @AbhinavSinghMaurya You can't make the free app to paid and viceversa. But yes you can implement the In-App Billing for your application and provide users to purchase the paid products of your application.

Comment: @Grishu you CAN make a paid app free but cannot make free app paid...

Comment: The only option you can do is remove your app from market(warning all your old customers will be removed) and then reupload app as a paid app

Comment: Now What should I do in this scenario. Because I can't re-upload, already existing users are there

Comment: You should implement the In-App billing in your application and provide the purchased products .

Comment: How about taking your existing app, and then adding a flavor to it with a different app id and then in your free one have an add that explains why people would benefit in downloading the paid one and just link directly to it as an upgrade from the free app. This way you still maintain one app.

Answer (score 7):

> Now as per our requirement I want to change it to paid app.

That is not possible. You can make a paid app be free, but you cannot make a free app be paid.

> But somewhere I found that a free app cannot be changed to paid app whereas a paid app can be changed to free app.

Correct.

> Then presently how can I achieve that???

You don't. Whoever provided this "requirement" needs to be fired due to ethics violations, IMHO.

However, you can:

- Upload a better app, under a new package name, and offer it as a "pro" edition, that you charge for
- Use in-app purchasing with your existing app to "unlock" some new features that you add
- Discontinue development on the original app and re-upload the app under a new package name as a paid app, though you will lose all existing users (and get a bunch of one-star ratings as a result, in all likelihood)